# Application of pythagoras theorem

Tags: geometry

> A cathedral spire $200$ ft high is $250$ ft away from a church steple which is $150$ ft high. At the same instant, two crows, one from each, fly of at the same speed heading toward some grain that is on a level, straight road connecting two towers. The crows reach the grain at the same instant. How far along that road is the grain from the cathedral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** To each triangle you can apply Pythagoras, and then you can go ahead and solve for $x$ and $y$.

[image: diagram of the problem]

Comment: I like the picture!

Answer (score 1):

Draw a picture.  Let $p$ be the distance of the grain from the cathedral, which is a calculus cathedral, namely a *line* going straight up. Let $q$ be the distance of the grain from the church. Then $q+p=200$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem, $250^2+p^2=150^2+q^2$. So we have the equations 
$$q+p=200,\qquad\text{and}\qquad q^2-p^2=250^2-150^2=(100)(400).$$
This can be solved pretty quickly. Hint: It is easy to find $q-p$.